# How to find the possible values in this number and the sum of its digits?

Tags: arithmetic, cryptography, number-systems

The problem is as follows:

$\textrm{Find the sum of a+b+c}$

$\overline{abc}=\overline{c000}_{(3)}$

What I have tried is to transform back to base $10$ the number on base $3$ by doing the following:

$\overline{c000}_{(3)}=3^{3}\times c+3^{2}\times 0+3^{1}\times 0 +3^{1}\times 0 + 3^{0}\times 0$

therefore:

$\overline{c000}_{(3)}=27\times c$

Then I came up with the idea that $c$ can only be (judging from the numeric system above) only $1$ or $2$ since a base $3$ number limits to those values. But if I do multiplication between $1$ or $2$ by $27$. It does not produce a number of three digits.

$27\times 1=27$

$27\times 2=54$

However I know that the sum of the numbers which results from multiplication of a number of divisibility by $9$ (in this case $27$) with any other number is equal to $9$.

Therefore let's say if

$27\times 4=108$

$1+0+8=9$

But the above procedure does not seem to be right as $4$ is off the limits from the base in the number.

I'm not sure if the sum of $a+b+c=9$, but if it is, is there any way to prove it? Did I made a mistake?

Comment: Yes, this is a badly formed question.  There is no such $a$, $b$, and $c$.  I think what was intended was that $c=5$, which gives the number 135, but, as you pointed out, we must have $c<3$, so this is not actually a solution.  There is none.  Where did this question come from?

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I restored the tag that you removed. Sources belong [to this site] [1], [Book by Neal Kobitz (number theory)] [2], [An article in Journal of Computer Applications] [3], as all indicate as change of base in numbers are within the realm of cryptography and by the way as it is used in this problem its of right use.
[1]: http://gpgtools.tenderapp.com/kb/how-to/introduction-to-cryptography 
[2]: http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=BA3SBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false 
[3]: http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume118/number14/pxc3903150.pdf

Comment: @Matthew Conroy I transcribed this question from an old exam, the alternatives given for the answer (that is the sum of $a+b+c$) were $9,12,15,8,16$ as I mentioned my best guess was that it could be $9$ but not sure if that would apply. Can you explain how did you get to the number $c=5$ as what it was intended?. If that would be the case, wouldn't the base be $6$? therefore $6^{3}\times 5+6^{3}\times 0+6^{2}\times 0+6^{1}\times 0=1080$ making it a four digit number.

Comment: @Matthew Conroy What i've found is $\overline{432}_{(10)}=\overline{2000}_{6}$ and $\overline{864}_{10}=\overline{4000}_{6}$ check with the way how it would had been intended provided that the base three is incorrect, pluggin other numbers by increasing the base $7,8,9$ exceed the 3 digit capacity in the base 10 number. Therefore I think the numbers from above could be the answer but their sum is different $4+3+2=9$ and $8+6+4=18$ unless you follow up the sum of the second option as $1+8=9$ but wouldn't it be forcing it to be $9$?, sorry I'm slow with these things, is my rationale correct?.

Comment: You do know that last "paper" you quoted is total BS?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If you have a problem with the content of the paper you could contact their authors directly. In this age people should be more tolerant to those who aren't at their level of enlightenment.

Comment: I'm just questioning "base change" as part of cryptography. I remain unconvinced.

Comment: I put my method in an answer.  I also think this is not cryptography: the fact that base-changing can be used in cryptography does not mean that all base-related problems are part of, or related to, cryptography.  I encourage the removal of the cryptography tag. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If the number $n=\overline{abc}=\overline{c000}_\beta$, then
$$
c\beta^3 = 100a+10b+c
$$
so 
$$c(\beta^3-1)=100a+10b$$
with $1\le c < \beta, 0 \le a,b \le 9$.  Since $100a+10b<1000$, we conclude that $\beta < 10$.  Checking all possibilities then yields $432=2\cdot 6^3$ and $864=4\cdot 6^3$ as the only solutions to the problem.

The base $3$ specification yields no solution.  The problem is incorrectly written.

Comment: It is a nice observation but I don't understand what happens with the left side of the equation I mean $c(\beta^{3}-1)$ How does this is used with the other inequalities to conclude $\beta<10$? In other words can you add more steps? this part I'm a bit lost.

Comment: $100a+10b\le990$, so $\beta^3 \le 991$ so $\beta<10$. Cheers!